# Run bash variable in mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

I'm writing a script to pull the DB information from a wp-config.php file and use that to login to mysql and then run a command to create a new user.

Yes this sounds like a major hacker script but I'm more trying to troubleshoot.

For purposes of shortening up this post I'll summarize the first part:

```bash
db=user_database
usr=user_databaseuser
ps=database_password
qr=mysql command

mysql --user=$usr --password=$ps $db
```

Now here is where I have troubles, I have another variable $qr that I'm trying to call once logged into mysql. I have tried:

```bash
-e $qr
```

on the end of that mysql command to login. When I try to use that method it does not do anything. I have also tried:

```bash
mysql --user=$usr --password=$ps $db < cat $qr or < echo $qr
```

With these ones I get a syntax error reporting cat and echo as an unknown command.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Error messages? Please be more specific, otherwise people cannot help.

Comment: `foo < cat x` doesn't make any sense. What you probably mean is `cat x | foo` The argument to `<` or `>` must be a filename, not another command.

Comment: Quote `$qr` (and if it still doesn't work, use `set -x`...)

Comment: Note BTW that username, password, database, and a lot more, can more easily be set by using a `--defaults_file`.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
echo $qr | mysql --user=$usr --password=$ps $db
```

or

```
mysql --user=$usr --password=$ps $db -e "$qr"
```

Comment: thanks sorry for the long reply, thats what I ended up using a variation of